# Value counts of column of 2 dataframes stacked shows double y-label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show the value counts of the column Audience of 2 dataframes stacked on each other. The y label is showing the Audience twice. Is there a way to remove that please?

[Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zK01.png)

```
DFGroup.Audience.value_counts().sort_values().unstack('Key').plot(kind = 'barh', stacked = True)
```

The code is found above. I also want to change the color scheme

Comment: which exact data/code have you used?

Comment: Hard to answer without a fully reproducible code, but I guess you can try: `DFGroup.Audience.value_counts().sort_values().unstack('Key').droplevel(1).plot(kind = 'barh', stacked = True)`